# Oracle replication A->B and B<-A?

Tags: oracle, replication, high-availability

If you have two unrelated Oracle databases on separate servers, can you replicate A to B and B to A so both servers have a copy of both db's?

Idea is for DR "on the cheap" without buying more Oracle Enterprise licenses.  As long as one server could handle the load if required, it seems worth trying.  But do Data Guard or other tools let you cross-replicate like this?

Answer (score 0):

If the foreign database on the "other" server can be readonly, you can google for "materialized view". Short: On connection (must be triggered) the server fetches the updates. They are really easy to setup.

If you need an instant standby with write replication from both servers I'm sure its possible but I've never done that and cant help there.

edit: 
oh, i've to add from oracle docs.... Write replication seems to be possible with this too.

> For replication purposes, materialized views allow you to maintain copies of remote data on your local node. The copies can be updatable with the Advanced Replication feature and are read-only without this feature. You can select data from a materialized view as you would from a table or view. In replication environments, the materialized views commonly created are primary key, rowid, object, and subquery materialized views.

Comment: Thanks. There probably are two underlying questions:  One, which replication methods (e.g.,  Streams) can cross-replicate?  Two, if people aren't doing this, what hidden gotchas are stopping them?